# mysqldump の --flush-logs オプションは何の目的で付与される？

Tags: mysql

[よく使うmysqldumpのオプションと使用例](https://qiita.com/ryounagaoka/items/7be0479a36c97618907f) を見ていました。

そこでは、 mysqldump を行うにあたっては、 --flush-logs を付与すると良い、ということが書いてあります。

#### 質問

- mysqldump において、 --flush-logs を行う理由は何ですか？

  - これを付与しなかった場合、どのようなトラブルが想定されますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ざっくりいうと復元の際に便利だからですね。
省略すると、作業手順が増えるので、復旧に時間がかかると言ったことが考えられます。

- ダンプからリストアした場合は、ダンプ取得時の古い状態になります。
  バイナリログからロールフォワードリカバリを行えば、ダンプ取得後～障害発生直前までに戻せます。
- `--flush-logs` は バイナリログがローテートされて新しいファイルが作成されるオプションです。
  復元時は 新しいバイナリログの先頭から リカバリを行えば良く、古いバイナリログは無視できます。
- オプションを省略した場合は、バイナリログから復元ポイントを探して、そのポジションを `--start-positon` で指定する必要があります。